# changing disabled property of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html button, and I have dynamically disabled it using the following property values

```
disabled="disabled"
```

How can i make it work again? i dont want to make it disabled now

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just set the [`disabled` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Property/disabled) to `false` in JavaScript, like this:

```
document.getElementById("myId").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var e = document.getElementById("someElement");
e.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

and disable again,

```
e.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: Better to just use the reflected property: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-50886781

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you explain why it is better to use the reflected property? Does it allow the browser to make some optimizations? Thanks

Comment: @Ngob - It's just easier to get right, so it helps with maintainability and readability: `e.disabled = true`, `e.disabled = false`, `e.disabled = !e.disabled` (toggling), etc. Whereas using `setAttribute` it's easy to do something like this: `e.setAttribute("disabled", "")` and think that enables the control (it doesn't; **any** value, including `""`, means "disabled").